# Performance issue with multiple DropDownLists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page that lists a number of Agencies. There is a dropdownlist of Agency Types next to each Agency in the list.

I have this in my controller method setting up my view:

```
var agenciesViewModel = new AgencyViewModel
    {
        Agencies = _agenciesRepository.Agencies.ToList(),
        AgencyTypes = _agencyTypesRepository.AgencyTypes.ToList()
    };

return View("Agencies", agenciesViewModel);
```

And in my Agencies view:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">    

    @foreach (Agency agency in Model.Agencies)
    {
    <tr>
        <td><b>@agency.Name</b></td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("AgencyTypes" + agency.ID,
                new SelectList(Model.AgencyTypes, "AgencyTypeID", "Name"))
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The problem is that on this certain page, I have about 500 agencies listed, which means 500 dropdownlists. There are about 2000 agency types.

This is causing performance issues on the initial page load, it takes about 2 minutes to load the page. It almost seems like it's retrieving the AgencyTypes collection from the database each time it loops through an agency.

It also causes performance issues after the page load - if I click on one of the dropdowns, it takes about 15 seconds to open the list. I found this odd, as all the data has been loaded, but for some reason it's causing performance issues in my browser.

Am I setting up these dropdownlists correctly, or is there a better way that would improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is two-fold:

1. 500 agencies * 2000 agency types = 1,000,000 `<option>`s downloaded, most of which are duplicated
2. Downloading the agencies and agency types also involves downloading many `<td>`, `<select>` and `<option>` tags along with the data.

You can cut your download time by downloading the agencies and agency types as json data using Ajax, then building your table dynamically.

1. Your controller action should return minimal information to load a skeleton view.
2. In your view, use javascript and Ajax to download your list of agencies and agency types from your controller.
3. Build your `<table>` and `<select>`s based on the downloaded json data.

This way, not only are you reducing the overhead of downloading the data, you're also downloading the 2000 agency types once.

As for your delay on opening your drop down lists, this may be because they have 2000 entries in them.  The browser being used, version, OS, all may be factors in this issue.